# Issue in Union with Empty dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I wanted to append a dataframe to another empty dataframe in a loop and finally write to a Location.

My Code -

```
val myMap = Map(1001 -> "rollNo='12'",1002 -> "rollNo='13'")
val myHiveTableData = spark.table(<table_name>)
val allOtherIngestedData = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row],rawDataHiveDf.schema)
myMap.keys.foreach {
                    i => val filteredDataDf = myHiveTableData.where(myMap(i))
                         val othersDf = myHiveTableData.except(filteredDataDf)
                         allOtherIngestedData.union(othersDf)
                         filteredDataDf.write.format("parquer")................... //Writing to a Location in Parquet 
}

allOtherIngestedData.write. ..................... //Writing to a Location in Parquet
```

But there is no data in data in `allOtherIngestedData`.

If i do `allOtherIngestedData.count` it gives me -> `Long = 0`.

So How to Append to an empty Dataframe ?

The same can be observed here too -

```
val rawDataHiveDf = spark.table(allInputs("inputHiveTableName"))
val allOthersDf : DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row],rawDataHiveDf.schema)
allOthersDf.union(rawDataHiveDf)
allOthersDf.count
```

O/p -

```
rawDataHiveDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [eventclassversion: string, serialnumber: string ... 33 more fields]
allOthersDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [eventclassversion: string, serialnumber: string ... 33 more fields]
res46: Long = 0
```

Scala Version = 2.11

Apache Spark = 2.4.3

Answer (score 1):

Working well on sample df.

```scala
val df = spark.range(2).withColumn("name", lit("foo"))
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    /**
      * +---+----+
      * |id |name|
      * +---+----+
      * |0  |foo |
      * |1  |foo |
      * +---+----+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: long (nullable = false)
      * |-- name: string (nullable = false)
      */
    val emptyDF = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext.emptyRDD[Row],df.schema)
    emptyDF.show(false)

    /**
      * +---+----+
      * |id |name|
      * +---+----+
      * +---+----+
      */

    emptyDF.unionByName(df)
      .show(false)
    /**
      * +---+----+
      * |id |name|
      * +---+----+
      * |0  |foo |
      * |1  |foo |
      * +---+----+
      */
```

Comment: Thanks @Someshwar Kale, The above example did work for me too. But my code isnt working. What could be the possible cause for this ?

Comment: why do you not assigning `allOtherIngestedData.union(othersDf)` to any variable and using that variable.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, so you mean i should do something like this - `val TempUnionDF = allOtherIngestedData.union(othersDf)` and then Write this to the desired location ? But What I want is , All rejected data  should go to a dataframe and then finally be written to a location. If I do like I mentioned in this comment then , n times (number of times looped) i write to that location, there will be n duplicates of my `PARTITION columns` right ? ( FYI - My partition column is `ingestiontime` )

Comment: This SO is regarding whether the union is working with the empty df or not? I would suggest just run this code and confirm that first - ```val filteredDataDf = myHiveTableData.where("rollNo='12'")
                         val othersDf = myHiveTableData.except(filteredDataDf)
                         allOtherIngestedData.union(othersDf).show()```

Comment: Yupp Its working. But I am doing exactly the same thing. The only difference being , This part is under a loop. Even if we ignore the main code, in the later part of my issue, -`val rawDataHiveDf = spark.table(allInputs("inputHiveTableName"))
val allOthersDf : DataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row],rawDataHiveDf.schema)
allOthersDf.union(rawDataHiveDf)
allOthersDf.count` , I dont seem to understand why this is not working ? In this code, if I assign the union to a variable it starts working, i.e `val tempDf=allOthersDf.union(rawDataHiveDf)` then it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the union needs to be stored in a separate DataFrame. Simply performing the union operation won't update allOthersDf. You can do so as follows:

`val combinedDF = allOthersDf.union(rawDataHiveDf)`

Optionally, if you wish to update the `allOthersDf` DataFrame specifically, you can instantiate it as a `var` instead of `val` and then do:

`allOthersDf = allOthersDf.union(rawDataHiveDf)`

Although this will create a new DataFrame as usual, `allOthersDf` will now refer to this new DataFrame.